# lookback API where filter with multiple conditions

Tags: loopbackjs

When using loopback API, is 'AND' operator redundant in 'where' filter with multiple conditions?
For example, I tested the following two queries and they return the same result:

```
<model>.find({ where: { <condition1>, <condition2> } });
<model>.find({ where: { and: [<condition1>, <condtion2>] } });
```

To be more specific, suppose this is the table content:

```
name   value
----   -----
a      1
b      2
```

When I execute 'find()' using two different 'where' filters, I get the first record in both cases:

```
{ where: { name: 'a', value: 1 } }
{ where: { and: [ { name: 'a'}, { value: 1 } ] } }
```

I've read through the API documents, but didn't find what logical operator is used when there are multiple conditions. 
If 'AND' is redundant as shown in my test, I prefer not using it. But I just want to make sure if this is true in general, or if it just happens to work with postgreSQL which I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a valid query which could only be accomplished with an and statement.

```
  {
    "where": {
      "or": [
        {"and": [{"classification": "adn"}, {"series": "2"}]},
        {"series": "3"}
      ]
    }
  }
```

EDIT: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-filters/blob/master/index.js

```
function matchesFilter(obj, filter) {
  var where = filter.where;
  var pass = true;
  var keys = Object.keys(where);
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    if (key === 'and' || key === 'or') {
      if (Array.isArray(where[key])) {
        if (key === 'and') {
          pass = where[key].every(function(cond) {
            return applyFilter({where: cond})(obj);
          });
          return pass;
        }
        if (key === 'or') {
          pass = where[key].some(function(cond) {
            return applyFilter({where: cond})(obj);
          });
          return pass;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!test(where[key], getValue(obj, key))) {
      pass = false;
    }
  });
  return pass;
}
```

It iterates through the keys of the `where` object where looking for failure, so it acts like an implicit `and` statement in your case.

EDIT 2: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/cc60ef8202092ae4ed564fc7bd5aac0dd4119e57/test/relations.test.js

The loopback datasource juggler contains tests which use the implicit `and` format

```
{PictureLink.findOne({where: {pictureId: anotherPicture.id, imageableType: 'Article'}},

{pictureId: anotherPicture.id, imageableId: article.id, imageableType: 'Article',}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. I understand 'and' is needed in conjunction with other logical operator. My question is about simple query with multiple conditions. I added an example to clarify my question.

Comment: I see. Thank you for finding the code. It would be nice if the official document mentions the default behavior.

Comment: This isn't used by [`loopback-connector`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector) or [`loopback-datasource-juggler`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler). And it's only used in [one location] in `PersistedModel`, and it doesn't appear to be doing anything with the the `where` clause.

Comment: @AndrewFerk Damn you're correct, though the repository implements 'LoopBack style filtering', implying that it contains the standard behavior.  There are too many connectors to check if their `buildWhere` methods are based on keys, maybe I can find something in a test

Answer (score 0):

> But I just want to make sure if this is true in general, or if it just happens to work with postgreSQL which I'm using.

Is it true in general? No.

It appears that this is handled for PostgreSQL and MySQL (and probably other SQL databases) in [`SQLConnector`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector/blob/master/lib/sql.js). So, it is possible connectors not using `SQLConnector` (e.g MongoDB) don't support this. However, given the many examples I've seen online, I would say it's safe to assume other connectors have implemented it this way, too.